# Setting A Date to End the Use of a Section of a SQL Script

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL 2005.  For one of our customers, we run a script everytime we set-up a new database.  The script defines what information remains and what information is deleted from the database....we use a master database to set 'typical' default information.  I have been asked to add a delete statement to the script with a 'test' for the delete statement to quit running automatically after 1 January 2011.  We don't want any other information if the script affected; just the one statement.  Does anyone know how to structure the syntax for this kind of request?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
IF GETDATE() < '20110101'
BEGIN
--Deletez
END
```

You may need to cast, but i don't think so `CAST('20110101' AS DATETIME)`